# Recorrido de bucle While sin obedecer condicional

Tags: java

Buenas, estoy haciendo un código desde dos clases distintas (dos elementos *.java diferentes), en la primera ('pelota') establezco los atributos y métodos:

```
public class Pelota {
 byte posX = 0;
 byte posY = 0;
 byte peso = 5;

     public Pelota(){
        this.posX = 0;
        this.posY = 0;
        this.peso = 5;}

 public void moverEnX() {
     this.posX = posX++;}
public void moverEnY(){
    this.posX = posY++;}}
```

Para después abrir una clase ('Main') a parte desde la cual crear un nuevo objeto pelota que se mueva un número de pasos determinado,

```
public class MainPelota {
public static void main (String [] args){
    Pelota objeto1 = new Pelota();
    System.out.println("la posicion inicial de objeto1 es: " + objeto1.posX +"\n Hay un foso en la casilla 8");

    objeto1.posX = 0;

    while (objeto1.posX<8){
        System.out.println("La pelota avanza, ahora está en la posición" + objeto1.posX);

    objeto1.moverEnX();

    if (objeto1.posX>=8){
        System.out.println("La pelota se ha caído");}
        }
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, al ejecutarlo lo único que hace es imprimir la sentencia del bucle While indefinidamente, sin que 'posX' avance, intuyo que el problema está a la hora de cumplir con el método 'moverEnX' pero no entiendo por qué no funciona si es capaz de acceder a 'posX' sin problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en la funcion `moverEnX()`

```
public void moverEnX() {
     this.posX = posX++;
}
```

Cuando el operador ++ esta a la derecha de la variable, incrementa el valor **pero retorna el valor anterior que tenia la variable**... es decir que si vale 5, le suma uno y cambia el valor de la variable a 6, pero al estar a la derecha, retorna 5. Luego el operador = establece la variable en 5, ya que es lo que recibe.

Dicho de otro modo, `posX` cambia a 6, pero inmediatamente vuelve a cambiar a 5.

Básicamente, nunca sale del bucle, por que desde el punto de vista del while, `posX` nunca cambia.

Ahora, como `posX++` **ya hace la asignación** del nuevo valor, no hay necesidad de hacerlo usando el operador `=`. Esto seria suficiente:

```
public void moverEnX() {
     posX++;
}
```

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias, tenías razón y la verdad es que era algo bastante sencillo.

Comment: De nada, no olvides marcar alguna respuesta como correcta saludos

Answer (score 1):

```
//Simplemente, cambia en los métodos eso y listo.

public class Pelota {

    byte posX;
    byte posY;
    byte peso;

     public Pelota(){
        this.posX = 0;
        this.posY = 0;
        this.peso = 5;
     }

    public void moverEnX() {
        posX++;

    }
    public void moverEnY(){
        posY++;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pelota objeto1 = new Pelota();
        System.out.println("la posicion inicial de objeto1 es: " + objeto1.posX +"\n Hay un foso en la casilla 8");


        while (objeto1.posX<8){
            System.out.println("La pelota avanza, ahora está en la posición: " + objeto1.posX);

            objeto1.moverEnX();

            if (objeto1.posX>=8){
                System.out.println("La pelota se ha caído");
            }
        }
    }
}
```